# DAX equivalent to sql statement that includes union, dummy column, and alias

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to write a PowerBI DAX expression that has:
a) union
b) alias for a column
c) dummy column

In SQL I write it like this:

```
select distinct bill_lvl_1 as unique_values, "bill_lvl_1" as source from main_table
union
select distinct bill_lvl_2 as unique_values, "bill_lvl_2" as source from main_table;
```

How do I do that with DAX expression?

Comment: Why exclude yourself from the members of this community who are versed in DAX but not in SQL?

Comment: Hey @JosWoolley, apologies but I don't understand your feedback. Appreciate it if you elaborate. Thanks

Comment: By asking for a translation from SQL to DAX, you're losing any chance of getting help from users who are familiar with DAX but not with SQL. An example dataset together with expected result would avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

```
VAR values1 =    
       SELECTCOLUMNS(
           VALUES(main_table)
           ,"unique_values", 'main_table'[bill_lvl_1 ])
       )
VAR values1AndDummy =
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            values1
            ,"source","bill_lvl_1"

VAR values2 = ...
VAR values2AndDummy = ...


RETURN 
    UNION(values1AndDummy,values2AndDummy)
```

Comment: you can mark it as answer. If any question, please, ask.